# How to allow Customer Community Login users see internal users?

Tags: sharing, lightning-community

Organization-Wide Defaults settings for the User object

[image]

I tried using Sharing Rules, but it didn't work since Customer Community Login license doesn't support sharing rules.

[image]

What I need is to allow a Customer Community Login user to see an internal user (like System Admin) in community. How can this be done?

Comment: Could you try enabling `Community User Visibility` from sharing setting? With that enabled, my community user is able to select a system administrator in a custom user lookup field on Account.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned it before, we want community users to see only their peers from the same account and internal users. With Community User Visibility set to TRUE community users will see absolutely all users in the community. That's why we set Portal User Visibility to TRUE and Community User Visibility to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your OWD on User object, set "Default external access" to "public read only".